Updating the src attribute of the img tag in HTML results in overlapping with old images
I continuously send binary streams of images from the backend server to the frontend HTML page. After receiving the binary stream, the frontend HTML page uses the URL.nestObjectionURL function to convert it and directly applies it to the src attribute of the img tag, just like this
socket.onmessage = function (event) {
    document.getElementById('img').src = URL.createObjectURL(event.data)
}

I continuously display new images transmitted from the backend by updating the src attribute of the img tag
But new images will always be displayed overlaid with old images

This phenomenon is very strange. As long as my perspective remains in the current window, it will cause this. Once my perspective leaves the current page, it will return to normal. Just like the image below, it is not overlaid with the old image

Oh my god, I'm really going to crash. I'm a beginner in HTML and I can't find any explanation for this phenomenon online. Can you please help me

I'm not familiar with the URL.nestObjectionURL function - can you explain it a little more

You aren't  calling URL.revokeObjectURL(objectURL) after each switch. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/revokeObjectURL_static
The dom is still keeping the reference to the url, when you leave the page and return it dumps those and restarts.
MDN also doesn't recommend using that method with streams anymore

You’re taking a screenshot of a screenshot of a screenshot…

The program I want to implement is: I hope the front-end HTML page can continuously display the images transmitted from the server
That's why we chose to use the method of constantly updating img tags to display the latest images sent by the server, but the implementation effect is not ideal now. Do you have a better way
The URL.estObjectionURL function is used to convert binary data into a src path that can be directly applied to img tags, as the server transmits binary data

I have tried the URL.revokeObject URL function, which causes the image to not be displayed. As soon as the image is loaded, this function clears the src and the image disappears

To put it simply, I actually wanted to implement a screen sharing feature. My initial idea was to continuously capture the screen and then transmit it to another person on the server to achieve screen sharing. This method is so foolish. Do you have a better idea for implementing it
